# How to choose and save multiple selections in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In Swift 3, how can I choose multiple selections in a tableview and save them? If I move back I want see what I selected before and change it! I am using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

When I open tableview and choose rows, all is OK. I can make my choices and go to the next ViewController. But when I move back to TableView I didn't see my selected rows and can't change my selection.

```
var selectedRows = Array<IndexPath>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   subServicesTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SubServicesTableViewCell

    cell.subServiceName.text = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath).name

    if !selectedRows.isEmpty {
        for row in selectedRows {
            if row == indexPath {
                cell.isSelected = true
                cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentCell = subServicesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SubServicesTableViewCell

    currentCell.chooseMark.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    selectedSubServices.append(fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath))
    selectedRows.append(indexPath)
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentCell = subServicesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SubServicesTableViewCell
    currentCell.chooseMark.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    selectedSubServices = selectedSubServices.filter(){$0 != fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath)}
    selectedRows = selectedRows.filter(){$0 != indexPath}
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for index in selectedRows {
        if index == indexPath {

            self.subServicesTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            if let serviveCell = cell as? SubServicesTableViewCell {
                serviveCell.chooseMark.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to introduce some kind of persistency for your choices. You could simply introduce a singleton, what keeps reference to the choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of recreating `selectedRows` every time your viewController is loaded, introduce a singleton where you can keep track of your selected `IndexPath` instances.

Here is simple implementation of a singleton class:

```
class RowsManager {
    static let shared = RowsManager()
    private init() {}
    var selectedRows = Array<IndexPath>()
}
```

From now on, instead of interacting with `selectedRows`, use `RowsManager.shared.selectedRows`.

Using a singleton is quick and fairly easy solution. However, there are many persistency techniques in the iOS echo system, like [userdefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) or writing to [file system](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better manage selection state yourself. UITableView will clear selection state when `reloadData()`, `reloadSections...`, `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...` been called.

for your station, it's system behavior. UIKit will deselect automatically When the user pops back from the detail view controller.

To reslove it, just store selectoin state, and restore it when you need.

```
    var selections = [NSIndexPath]()
    ...
    ...
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if !selections.contain(indexPath) {
        selections.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```